# Ubuntu 16.04 won't suspend/hibernate. It turns off directly.

Tags: 16.04, kernel, suspend, encryption, hibernate

I am runnning Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.8.0-54-generic (full: #57~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 16:22:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), running unity, with full disk encryption (see partition set up below using default installer options), I have checked that I have SWAP and as of a few minutes ago, I am fully up to date with updates. Every time I try to suspend/hibernate, the laptop just powersoff (but in a faster way than the actual power off) - i.e. if I power off, it takes a few seconds to run some checks, kill processes, etc. If I suspend, it just goes off after 1 second.

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─sda2                    8:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot
├─sda3                    8:3    0   476G  0 part  
│ └─sda3_crypt          253:0    0   476G  0 crypt 
│   ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 468.1G  0 lvm   /
│   └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   7.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
└─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
```

This happens whether I close the lid, or even use the top right menu to click 'suspend', and even if I use the `sudo pm-suspend` command.

I already tried changing /etc/systemd/logind.conf to have HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend but nothing does it.

This problem did not use to happen on older kernels and only happened when updated (but I did not keep track of which was the last kernel it worked on). I have tried this on a non-full disk encrypted laptop and I have the same problem, so I don't think it's an encryption thing. It's crazy that this would happen to all laptops running this particular kernel..

I have also tried all of these options (separately of course!) in /etc/default/grub, again to no avail

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Any help/pointers would help. I am aware of this bug tracker but nothing there has helped: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302

Thank you!

Comment: Doing it make a difference if you log off first and then shut the lid?

Comment: @Robby1212 I tried but nothing changes..?